# Misterious DefaultSPGroupsAsync Feature

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, features

In SharePoint Online, as part of the Modern Team site, there is a  **DefaultSPGroupsAsync** **Web** feature with the ID e233eb34-e720-4ff9-9f53-a5aabc706d12.

Does anyone know what this feature is supposed to do? I could not find any documentation describing it. I have checked if this feature exusted as part of a classic Team site and it it's not present there. So I am curious what this does exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DefaultSPGroupsAsync** (e233eb34-e720-4ff9-9f53-a5aabc706d12) is a hidden feature responsible for ensuring the default SharePoint groups have correct names. After site is provisioned, this feature applies names to the Visitors, Members and the Owners group. It also adds a default owner to the Owners SharePoint Group.

All in all, this feature is useless for any custom purposes. There are no uses cases for this feature in the real world.

[image]